# Trying to find my error in my QuickSort Algorithm

Tags: python, quicksort

Heres my QuickSort Algorithm that I came up with. The first function is the Partitioning, and the second function is the QuickSorting of an array.

```
def Partition(A ,start, end):

    pivot = A[end]

    p_index = start

    for i in range(start,end-1):
    
        if A[i] <= pivot:
            #swap
            A[i], A[i-1] = A[p_index], A[i]
        
            p_index = p_index +1

    # this is swaping the pivot point between the sorted values
    A[p_index], A[end] = A[end], A[p_index]

    return p_index


     
def QuickSort(A, start, end):


    if start < end:
        return

    p_index = Partition(A, start, end)

    # recursive Calls here:
    
    QuickSort(A, start, p_index-1)

    QuickSort(A,p_index +1, end)
```

The original array is returned unsorted

```
array = [2,1,3,6,8,5,7,4]

n = len(array)

QuickSort(array,0,n-1)

print(array)
```

returned: [2,1,3,6,8,5,7,4]

Comment: Did you make any attempt at debugging the code? For example, did you check what `A` contains before and after the call to `Partition`? Did you check what it contains after each swap operation? Do the results make sense to you?

Comment: Your definition of `Quicksort` has a base case of `if start < end`, yet you pass `start=0` and `end=6`. Therefore, 0 < 6

Comment: after you fix the base case check, I suggest you check A after the first call to Partition.

Answer (score 0):

Your base case logic is incorrect.

You want to return when 'start' is greater or equal to 'end':

```
def QuickSort(A, start, end):


   if start >= end:
       return

   p_index = Partition(A, start, end)

   # recursive Calls here:

   QuickSort(A, start, p_index-1)

   QuickSort(A,p_index +1, end)
```